# how to decrypt a password and send mail in php

Tags: php, mysql

i had Encrypted my password in register.php

```
    <?php
// Set error message as blank upon arrival to page
$errorMsg = "";
// First we check to see if the form has been submitted 
if (isset($_POST['username'])){
    //Connect to the database through our include 
    include_once "connect_to_mysql.php";
    // Filter the posted variables
    $username = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['username']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    $country = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['country']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $state = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['state']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $city = ereg_replace("[^A-Z a-z0-9]", "", $_POST['city']); // filter everything but spaces, numbers, and letters
    $accounttype = ereg_replace("[^a-z]", "", $_POST['accounttype']); // filter everything but lowercase letters
    $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    $password = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
    // Check to see if the user filled all fields with
    // the "Required"(*) symbol next to them in the join form
    // and print out to them what they have forgotten to put in
    if((!$username) || (!$country) || (!$state) || (!$city) || (!$accounttype) || (!$email) || (!$password)){

        $errorMsg = "You did not submit the following required information!<br /><br />";
        if(!$username){
            $errorMsg .= "--- User Name";
        } else if(!$country){
            $errorMsg .= "--- Country"; 
        } else if(!$state){ 
            $errorMsg .= "--- State"; 
       } else if(!$city){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- City"; 
       } else if(!$accounttype){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Account Type"; 
       } else if(!$email){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Email Address"; 
       } else if(!$password){ 
           $errorMsg .= "--- Password"; 
       }
    } else {
    // Database duplicate Fields Check
    $sql_username_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1");
    $sql_email_check = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM members WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");
    $username_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_username_check);
    $email_check = mysql_num_rows($sql_email_check); 
    if ($username_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your User Name is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    } else if ($email_check > 0){ 
        $errorMsg = "<u>ERROR:</u><br />Your Email address is already in use inside our system. Please try another.";
    } else {
        // Add MD5 Hash to the password variable
       $hashedPass = md5($password); 
        // Add user info into the database table, claim your fields then values 
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (username, country, state, city, accounttype, email, password, signupdate) 
        VALUES('$username','$country','$state','$city','$accounttype','$email','$hashedPass', now())") or die (mysql_error());
        // Get the inserted ID here to use in the activation email
        $id = mysql_insert_id();
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user files(pics, MP3s, etc.) 
        mkdir("memberFiles/$id", 0755); 
        // Start assembly of Email Member the activation link
        $to = "$email";
        // Change this to your site admin email
        $from = "geetha.victor@tryteksolutions.co.in";
        $subject = "Complete your registration";
        //Begin HTML Email Message where you need to change the activation URL inside
        $message = '<html>
        <body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        Hi ' . $username . ',
        <br /><br />
        You must complete this step to activate your account with us.
        <br /><br />
        Please click here to activate now &gt;&gt;
        <a href="http://www.trytek.tryteksolutions.co.in/activation.php?id=' . $id . '">
        ACTIVATE NOW</a>
        <br /><br />
        Your Login Data is as follows: 
        <br /><br />
        E-mail Address: ' . $email . ' <br />
        Password: ' . $password . ' 
        <br /><br /> 
        Thanks! 
        </body>
        </html>';
        // end of message
        $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
        $to = "$to";
        // Finally send the activation email to the member
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        // Then print a message to the browser for the joiner 
        print "<br /><br /><br /><h4>OK $firstname, one last step to verify your email identity:</h4><br />
        We just sent an Activation link to: $email<br /><br />
        <strong><font color=\"#990000\">Please check your email inbox in a moment</font></strong> to click on the Activation <br />
        Link inside the message. After email activation you can log in.";
        exit(); // Exit so the form and page does not display, just this success message
    } // Close else after database duplicate field value checks
  } // Close else after missing vars check
} //Close if $_POST
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Member Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="7%">REGISTER AS A MEMBER HERE </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="5">
  <form action="join_form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><font color="#FF0000"><?php echo "$errorMsg"; ?></font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="163"><div align="right">User Name:</div></td>
      <td width="409"><input name="username" type="text" value="<?php echo "$username"; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Country:</div></td>
      <td><select name="country">
      <option value="<?php echo "$country"; ?>"><?php echo "$country"; ?></option>
      <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
      <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
      <option value="United States">United States</option>
      <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">State: </div></td>
      <td><input name="state" type="text" value="<?php echo "$state"; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">City: </div></td>
      <td>
        <input name="city" type="text" value="<?php echo "$city"; ?>" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Account Type: </div></td>
      <td><select name="accounttype">
        <option value="<?php echo "$accounttype"; ?>"><?php echo "$accounttype"; ?></option>
        <option value="a">Normal User</option>
        <option value="b">Expert User</option>
        <option value="c">Super User</option>
      </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right">Email: </div></td>
      <td><input name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo "$email"; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Password: </div></td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" value="<?php echo "$password"; ?>" /> 
      <font size="-2" color="#006600">(letters or numbers only, no spaces no symbols)</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"> Captcha: </div></td>
      <td>Add Captcha Here for security</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <td><div align="right"></div></td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Form" /></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my forgot password script in which i have a problem in sending encrypt password in mail. how to decrypt a password and send decrypted password in mail.

```
<?php session_start();
include "connect_to_mysql.php"; //connects to the database
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query="select * from members where email='$email'";
    $result   = mysql_query($query);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    // If the count is equal to one, we will send message other wise display an error message.
    if($count==1)
    {
        $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $password  =  $rows['password'];//FETCHING PASS
        //echo "your pass is ::".($pass)."";
        $to = $rows['email'];
        //echo "your email is ::".$email;
        //Details for sending E-mail
        $from = "geetha.victor@tryteksolutions.co.in";
        $url = "http://abc.co.in/";
        $body  =  "TrytekSolutions password recovery <br />
        ---------------------------------------------------------- <br />
        Url : $url;<br />
        email Details is : $to;<br />
        Here is your password  : $password;<br /> <br />
        Sincerely, <br />
        TryTekSolutions";
        $from = "abc@tryteksolutions.co.in";
        $subject = "Tryteksolutions Password recovered";
        $headers1 = "From: $from\n";
        $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-Mailer: Just My Server\r\n";
        $sentmail = mail ( $to, $subject, $body, $headers1 );
    } else {
    if ($_POST ['email'] != "") {
    echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Not found your email in our database</span>";
        }
    }
    //If the message is sent successfully, display sucess message otherwise display an error message.
    if($sentmail==1)
    {
        echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Your Password Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.</span>";
    }
        else
        {
        if($_POST['email']!="")
        echo "<span style='color: #ff0000;'> Cannot send password to your e-mail address.Problem with sending mail...</span>";
    }
}
?>
```

help me friends how to decrypt a password and send mail.

Comment: You can't decrypt MD5

Answer (score 4):

Don't. You should never be able to convert the stored password data into an actual password. They should be hashed, not encrypted.

MD5 is a hashing algorithm, but a very weak one that is entirely [unsuitable](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) for protecting passwords with today. You need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

If someone loses their password, then generate a time-limited random reset token and email it to the user.

When they enter that token (usually by following a link in the email with the token embedded in it) allow them to choose a new password.

Comment: please explain with some example

Comment: I don't have time to write you a complete password reset system. If you need clarification on a specific point, then feel free to ask a more specific question.

Comment: i'm new to php so please help me out. i'm trying to learn php.

Comment: *more* specific, not *less* specific :)